# Using Dropbox, can I create a public link from a shared folder?

Tags: dropbox, links

When I have a folder shared between me and my collegue(s) via Dropbox, can I generate a public link of it (maybe by using Dropbox for Teams)?

I know there is the possibility to "Get a link" via right-clicking from the shared folder, but thats **not** what I want. The "Get Link" will create a link to the Dropbox website, where one has to download that file. But I need a "raw" link, that directly opens the file and is `wget` proof (The Dropbox download site relies on Javascript to work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link generated for a file is something like this:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/_someRandomStrings_/_theNameOfTheFile
```

If you replace *www* with *dl* it will take you directly to the respective file. Alternatively, adding `?dl=1` at the end of the link above, will redirect it to the `dl.dropbox.com` URL.

Now, if you have the link to a folder and you add `?dl=1` at the end, it will start downloading it as an archive.

[Source](http://www.macworld.com/article/2009999/directly-downloading-dropbox-files.html). And the [official source](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/201).

(I have tested the method and it works.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a source from Dropbox itself:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.