# Temporary storage webapp

Tags: download

I have a file `foo.zip`, that I want hosted on the internet somewhere, and that can be downloaded with a `wget` command. I have tried a few options (including Google Drive), but each time I end up downloading the *containing website*, as opposed to the file for which the download starts automatically.

Basically, I need a direct link to the file, e.g. `www.example.com/foo.zip`, as opposed to a "hashed" link such as `www.example.com/1928394819293840124857`. How can I host a file online *and* have a direct link to it for download with `wget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for this as well. Check the answers to [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31215/1512) question on Web Apps and [this](https://superuser.com/q/470664/33894) one on Superuser to see how you can link directly to the file you want to download.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use http://www.fileden.com/ as stated officially:

> Our service allows all customers to directly link to their files without annoying download pages or waiting times and comes with a standard yearly 99.5% uptime guarentee.